# CvBridge.h missing in Hydro armhf?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, cv-bridge, armhf, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to rosmake a self-written node in Hydro on armhf, but it fails on a missing CvBridge.h. "roscd cv_bridge" takes me to /opt/ros/hydro/share/cv_bridge$ and "ls" shows cmake  and package.xml. So where is the header file ?

Thanks,

- building vision-opencv en cv-bridge bring the message that the stacks are not found and it assumes the new build system is being used. Also the catkin stack is not found, while ros-hydro-catkin is installed and newest version. So if Hydro indeed does support rosbuild, why is it asking for catkin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/166291/cvbridge.h-missing-in-hydro-armhf-?/) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're also using the old CvBridge API, which has been deprecated for a long time, and which was removed starting in Groovy. See: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/8

With catkin, package headers are installed into /opt/ros/hydro/include/PACKAGE; you should be able to find the new cv_bridge headers there.

You can also list all of the files installed by a package with `dpkg -L ros-hydro-cv-bridge`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-05-18**:
Ok, ty. I found I made a mistake in my code. I first had cv_bridge.h, then according to info I found, I had to use CvBridge.h. Changing back to cv_bridge, it compiles fine. From your info, I guess catkin is used next to rosbuild ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-18**:
cv_bridge (and all of Hydro) is built and released with catkin. You can use it from both catkin and rosbuild packages.